# How to know that a control is loaded in .Net Compact Framework, WinForms application?

Tags: c#, compact-framework

How to know that a control is loaded in .Net Compact Framework, WinForms application?

Any ideas please...

Comment: To know from where?  The Control's code itself?  The containing/Parent Form?  Somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, in the control itself...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "loaded".  The constructor is called when the Control is created, so if you need to know when an instance is creatred, that's where you'd put it.

If you want to know when it gets put into a Form/Container, then overriding [OnParentChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onparentchanged%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is probably a good place to put your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by

```
 If Me.IsHandleCreated Then
  ' When winform is loaded
 End If
```